# action mailer gives error while passing layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

in my action mailer(rails 3.2.13) I have something like

```
class RepaymentMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "repayments@milaap.org"

  def repayment_mail user, user_repayment_info, month_date
    @mail_layout = if condition_true
                            'layout1'
                        else
                            'layout2'
                        end

  mail(to:        "#{user.first_name} <#{user.email}>",
     from:      "xxx@xxx.org",
     bcc:       ["xxx <xxx@xxx.org>"],
     reply_to:  'xxx@xxx.org',
     subject:   "this is a test" ) do |format|
      format.html { render layout: @mail_layout }
      format.text
    end
  end
end
```

when I do

```
puts RepaymentMailer.repayment_mail(param1, param2, param3).deliver
```

it gives me error that even if repayment_mail template exist

```
 ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template repayment_mailer/repayment_mail with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:text], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee, :arb]}. Searched in:
```

If I remove

```
 do |format|
      format.html { render layout: @mail_layout }
      format.text
    end
```

then It works without error. 
But Obviously I want the desired layout. What can be the cause of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in your error, it is clearly showing that problem is with this line:

```
 Missing template repayment_mailer/repayment_mail with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:text]**, :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee, :arb]}.
```

I think you didn't read the lines below:

```
 class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def welcome_email(user)
    mail(to: user.email) do |format|
      format.html { render layout: 'my_layout' }
      format.text
    end
  end
end
```

This will render the HTML part using the `my_layout.html.erb` file and the text part with the usual `user_mailer.text.erb` file if it exists.

Please read here.

Thanks

Comment: but in rails guides http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-layouts it is given like the same how I've implemented

Comment: Well, got it . It actually saying that text template is missing. Stupid mistake. thanks

Comment: Here you see : Will render the HTML part using the my_layout.html.erb file and the text part with the usual user_mailer.text.erb file if it exists.

Comment: your welcome. This is all part of web development. everybody does these mistakes.thanks